# Use part of an HTML file in templateUrl

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a way to use only part of a file as your directive's `templateUrl`? For example, if I have a file

```
<input type="text" data-name="first-name" />

<input type="text" data-name="last-name" />

<input type="text" data-name="address" />

etc.
```

is there a way for Angular to pull out only the "first name" `input` tag or only the "last name" `input` tag, as opposed to using the entire file?

I want to be able to have multiple directive's HTML content as a single HTML file, as having just one line of code seems like a waste of a file (UNIX philosophy has its limits). Also, I might want to concatenate these `templateUrl` files as part of my minification process, and I want to know Angular won't use the entire file for each directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to use just part of a template url; the entire thing gets pulled in and compiled.

For short templates, I've found that in lining the template with the directive can be a best practice. The reduction in context switching when it's only a little html tends to be worth it, imo.

This can be done by changing the tag from

```
templateUrl: 'foo.html'
```

to

```
template: '<input type="text" data-name="address" />'
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow that sucks, especially for minimization. As usual, Angular doesn't completely succeed in its quest to make HTML/JS modular. I knew about `template`, but I think there could be times where the HTML is too big to put in the directive definition, but too small for its own file.

Comment: Wow I just realized my question was answered already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130915/angularjs-directives-without-html-in-the-code?rq=1 :P Not sure if it counts as a duplicate, though, as it has a larger scope than mine.

Answer (score 0):

AngularUI has this functionality. In its `UI-Utils` package, there is the `ui-include` directive. This is exactly like the [`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) directive, except that it allows an extra attribute, `fragment`, which includes a part of a page, rather than a whole page, into itself.

The sample code on the [AngularUI UI-Utils](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils) page demonstrates quite well:

```
<ui-include src="'my/url/to/partial/file'" fragment="'#id-to-fragment'"></ui-include>
<!-- Don't forget to quote string literals! -->
<!-- Don't forget to include jQuery if you need full selector support! -->
```

Of course, you're probably including jQuery already. :)